# Where find configuration setting to HBase for simple connection

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to connect to HBase with haredb, but I am not able to find out what should I type to connection settings.

I have the simplest dummiest instalation, just ./bin/start-hbase.sh.

I have tried 127.0.0.1:2181
I have tried 127.0.1.1:2181 (I am on Ubuntu)
I have tried `localhost`:2181

fs.default.name is blank or `http://localhost:9000`
mapred.job.tracker is blank or `http://localhost:9001`

Do you have any idea where to find in config the host and port which I need?

Comment: Please post your hbase-site.xml file under conf folder of your installation path. Your problem may have many causes. Also you should comment the line containing 127.0.1.1 in your /etc/hosts folder.

Comment: Commenting 127.0.1.1 helps, it wasn't in hbase-site.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the hbase-site.xml and see which port and ip you've configured for your zookeeper.
Also make sure that zookeeper is up and running otherwise your hbase is down

Comment: it does have a zookeeper only it runs on the same JVM as the HBase master see section 2.2.1 http://hbase.apache.org/book/standalone_dist.html